# simple game to make only using python

Tags: python, graphics

I have only started learning python recently. I would still be considered a beginner. Does anyone know any simple games I could make using only python or python turtle. I have no experience with pygame or tkinter yet. The game does not need to use graphics. For example one of my recent games was trying to guess the letters of a random word. Simple game. Kind of like hangman. I will consider all answers. Thank you :)

Comment: Try the game "Pong" : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two that come to mind for me are Tic-Tac-Toe and Higher or Lower

Comment: Higher or lower is perfect. I've never thought of that. I was considering doing tic tac toe. I will probably do this after Higher or Lower. Thanks for the answer